# Is there a way to use different script functions without using gameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a c# file that containes utils functions in CommonUtils class. I want to use these functions from different c# files. Is there a way to access or import them without using gameObject? Or I just have to throw an empty game object, add util script to it and access gameObject and then CommonUtils script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a static class that implements public static functions that you would use in your other classes.

Here is an example of `SceneLoader` class that any other class can use to load scenes:

```
public static class SceneLoader
{
    // Load scene by name
    public static void LoadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Load scene by build index
    public static void LoadScene(int sceneBuildIndex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You would then use the functions within this class from other classes like so:

```
SceneLoader.LoadScene("my scene");
```

The same principle applies to your `CommonUtils` class.

If for some reason you need this class to inherit from `Monobehaviour`, consider applying the [Singleton](https://gamedevbeginner.com/singletons-in-unity-the-right-way/) pattern to it in order to access the instance without the need of referencing the game object each time.